# Getting error LNK2019 and LNK1120, can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

Tags: c++, lnk2019

I'm getting these errors:

> ```
> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall
> Animal::Animal(int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class
> std::allocator<char> >)" (??0Animal@@QAE@HV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?
> $allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function _wmain
>
> Error 2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
> ```

I've tried to google for answers, but I can't seem to get it to work...

```
// ConsoleApplication3.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

class Animal
{
protected:
    int age;
    string type;
public:
    void virtual sleep() { cout << type << " : Sleeping" << endl; }
    void virtual eat() { cout << type << " : Eating" << endl; }
    int getAge() { return age; }
    string getType() { return type; }
    Animal(int argAge) : age(argAge) {}
    Animal() : age(0) {}
    Animal::Animal(int, string);
};

class Lion : public Animal
{
public:
    void sleep() { cout << "The lion is sleeping" << endl; }

};

class Hamster : public Animal
{
public:
    void eat() { cout << "The hamster is eating" << endl; }
};

char YorN;
string aniType;
int eatOrSleep = 0;
int check = 0;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Lion scar;
    scar.eat();

    Hamster hammertime;
    hammertime.sleep();

    cout << "Would you like to create a new animal? y/n" << endl;
    cin >> YorN;
    if (YorN == 'y' || YorN == 'Y'){
        cout << "What kind of animal?:" << endl;
        cin >> aniType;
        Animal newAnimal(0, aniType);
        cout << "Congratualtions, you just created a" << newAnimal.getType() << endl;
        do
        {
            cout << "Enter either 1, 2 or 3:" << endl <<
                "1: Makes your animal sleep" << endl <<
                "2: Makes your animal eat" << endl <<
                "3: Exit the program" << endl;
            cin >> eatOrSleep;
            if (eatOrSleep == 1)
            {
                newAnimal.sleep();
            }
            else if (eatOrSleep == 2)
            {
                newAnimal.eat();
            }
            else if (eatOrSleep == 3)
            {
                check = 1;
                break;
            }
        } while (check == 0);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You've declared the constructor `Animal::Animal(int, string);` but not given a definition for it.

Answer (score 4):

Let's try to simplify the original long error message, reducing some "noise", to make the error message more easily understandable.

The original error message is:

> ```
> Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
> "public: __thiscall Animal::Animal(int, class std::basic_string<char,
> struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" 
> (??0Animal@@QAE@HV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) 
> referenced in function _wmain
> ```

First, the part containing `??0Animal@@QAE...` etc. can be discarded, since this is just C++ *name mangling*, and it's not meant to be human readable.

So, after this first step, the simplified error message becomes:

> ```
> Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Animal::Animal(int,
> class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)"
> referenced in function _wmain
> ```

This version without the C++ name mangling is clearer.
The linker is complaining about some missing method definition (and that method is referenced inside the `_wmain()` function).

Let's try to further simplify the error message, filtering out some more "noise":

1. The `__thiscall` is a calling convention used by C++ class methods.
2. The part:

   > ```
   > class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,
   >   class std::allocator<char>>
   > ```

   is just the long name of STL `std::string` (which is `std::basic_string` with `char` as character type, and using the standard allocator).

So, the error message can be further simplified as:

> ```
> Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: Animal::Animal(int, string)" 
> referenced in function _wmain
> ```

This is very clear: the linker is complaing about the missing definition of the `Animal` constructor of the form `Animal::Animal(int, string)`.

Just provide proper body for that constructor, e.g.:

```
class Animal {
....
public:

    Animal(int anAge, string aType)
        : age(anAge),
        , type(std::move(aType))  // C++11: pass by value and move from the value
    { }
....
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Animal::Animal(int, string);
```

You need to define the body of this function. Maybe that's what you want

```
Animal::Animal(int _age, string _type)
{
    age = _age;
    type = _type;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all this declaration of constructor with two parameters

```
Animal::Animal(int, string);
```

is invalid though MS VC++ compiles the code.

You must declare it without using qualified name

```
Animal(int, string);
```

As for the error messge then you forgot to define the constructor but call it in statement

```
Animal newAnimal(0, aniType);
```